# High sample renders appear transparent / blank

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes, error

So this is my scene :

[image]

When I render it using 128 samples or less, the final image is visible:

[image]

However, when I  increase the samples greater than that, the image is visible while rendering and then disappears after the composition is finished.After seeing a few posts on here, I found that turning off the sequencer allows it to render. But, the result was the same:

[image]

This is my compositor node setup:

[image]

I'm using Blender 2.79, could this be a bug?

**Edit:** Ok, so when I tried to render the scene again, it seemed to be successful to the 99% mark but then fails and becomes blank or black when it completes.

[image]

[image]

Compositor nodes :

[image]

**Update:** I tested the scene further and apparently it's the cloud layer under the islands that has been causing all the problems. I rendered each layer separately, and they rendered fine, except for the cloud object layer, which initially showed signs of rendering and then disappeared as soon as it finished.

This is the object's shader:

[image]

It is just a simple plane with these modifiers:

[image]

Any ideas what could be causing this and how I could fix it?

**PS:** When I say "cloud layer" I mean the cloud object, not any render layer.

Comment: Please show an image of your compositing nodes

Comment: @cegaton hang on

Comment: @cegaton I'm running another test render, but the compositor nodes are simple as of now, he render result is connected to the composite and viewer outputs... no other nodes are connecting them

Comment: @cegaton I added the compositor node setup too

Comment: Do you have more than one render layer? Are you looking at the correct one?

Comment: @cegaton nope, I haven't set any render layers

Comment: @cegaton I updated the details after testing out a few things, please have a look

Comment: Could be that you're running out of system resources, although an error should pop up in that case. Try increasing the step size or decreasing the max steps in the geometry panel in the render tab and render again with the same samples.

Comment: How much RAM is there in your system?

Comment: @cegaton I have 16GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the compositor is making your whole image transparent somehow when it applies the post processing effects. Try disabling the compositor to see if that fixes your issue. Have you changed anything other than the samples between renders? (New to Stack Exchange so can't comment this)

Comment: One way to probe and troubleshoot this is to add viewer nodes at points along the composite flow.